# How to use JDK 7 in Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to build a project that required JDK 7, and I tried : navigate to

```
File > Project Structure > SDK Location
```

and change the path to JDK 7, but an error was appeared
[please choose JDK 8 or newer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htdod.jpg)

Is there a way to use JDK 7 in Android Studio 2.3? Or I should use an older version of Android Studio?

**Edit**

I uninstall all JDK and then install JDK 7, and it's work!

Comment: Did you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the java home as correct path in environment variables. Check your java location in environment variable. Open cmd and type java -version and if it is not java 7 change it in the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

please check the current version of java in your machine 
go to terminal and do

```
java -version
```

check if it's 1.7.x

use the below command to find java path

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

suggestion -Android Studio does not like spaces in the paths to the Android SDK and the JDK. Installing the JDK in a location that does not contain any spaces allowed to update the location through the Project Structure window.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle :

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```